# C# field initializer error when using a hidden field variable

Tags: c#, hiddenfield

I'm very new to C#, so there's probably a very simple answer to this, it's just my noobness that's stopping me getting it.

I'm trying to extract a parameters value from a URL, and then pass it to a query string in code behind.

I've no problem getting the parameter value and pass it to a hiddenfield (that's being done in jQuery/HTML on the .aspx page), however when I try to use it's value 'URLVariable' in the code behind I consistently get 'A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'P1'' error

Making P1 static makes the error go away, but means that the value doesn't change when the page is reloaded, and that's really the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm pretty sure this is me failing to do constructors properly, but I can't see what I'm getting wrong.

Thanks for any help in advance, code is below.

```
public partial class SqlDat : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string P1;

public SqlDat()
{ (new SqlDat()).P1 = URLVariable.ToString(); }

public string tb1text = "SELECT Stuff FROM Somewhere WHERE Something= "+SqlDat.P1;//+ HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(BaseUrl.Query).Get("Tim");

}
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code. Where do the above code appear in you classes?

Comment: You didn't post the class definition in which these fields and the method SqlDat() are in. Please update.

Comment: The `public string tb1text` line refers to `P1` as if it's a static field (`TypeName.Field`). Just assign `tb1text` its value inside the `SqlDat` constructor, after you've assigned a value to `P1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your class looks like this:

```
public class SqlDat
{
    public string P1;

    public SqlDat()
    {
        P1 = URLVariable.ToString();
    }

    public string tb1text = "SELECT Stuff FROM Somewhere WHERE Something = "+SqlDat.P1;//+ HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(BaseUrl.Query).Get("Tim");
}
```

That won't work. First and foremost not because `SqlDat.P1` refers to a static member on the type `SqlDat`, which `P1` isn't, so you're looking for `this.P1` or simply `P1`.

If you want to refer to other members in an initializer, and especially *after* said member is initialized in the constructor, then you need to set it in the constructor:

```
public class SqlDat
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string tb1text { get; set; 

    public SqlDat()
    {
        P1 = URLVariable.ToString();
        tb1text = "SELECT Stuff FROM Somewhere WHERE Something = " + P1;
    }
}
```

Then you can let `P1` and `tb1text` be properties too (`{ get; set; }`).

You also may want to reconsider your naming, and whether to manually craft SQL strings (read about SQL injection), using an ORM instead of querying the database yourself and not using statics (where does `URLVariable` come from?).

Comment: You've still got a static reference in there SqlDat.P1 - just needs to be P1.

Comment: I think that's the answer, thanks guys. The advice on what I should be doing is also appreciated, Thanks CodeCaster.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access this field as a static member, which it is not. Instead you need to create an object of `SqlDat` and use P1 from there. Simplistically:

```
(new SqlDat()).P1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access a static property, and in your constructor you are creating a new instance. The below changes should work:

```
public partial class SqlDat : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string P1;

public SqlDat()
{ P1 = URLVariable.ToString(); }

public string tb1text = "SELECT Stuff FROM Somewhere WHERE Something= "+P1;//+ HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(BaseUrl.Query).Get("Tim");

}
```